# WMI class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory doesn't work

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to query the NUMA status from WMI on Windows 10.  This works on Supermicro 7049, HP Z840, and Asus PA90, but it fails on Supermicro 7048.  Is there some limitation about when this query is supported?  Other wmi queries work fine, so far this is the only one I'm having a problem with. Calling this method with Python WMI throws a similar error.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> gwmi -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory
gwmi : Invalid query "select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory"
At line:1 char:1
+ gwmi -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_NUMANodeMemory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: that reads like a glitch in the `Get-WmiObject` call OR the cmdlet itself. have you tried using the `CIM` version?

Comment: Good idea, I’ll try. I never use CIM. It’s probably not the Cmdlet because Python has the same issue.

Comment: ah! it you are seeing this from two different directions, then it may be a damaged CIM/WMI database. i vaguely recall seeing comments on that ... but have never had any reason to go into it myself.